# Making Nested ng-repeat in AngularJS dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to implement a table using ng-repeat for the following data :

```
    [{
    "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
    "City": "Berlin",
    "Country": "Germany"
}, {
    "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
    "City": "Luleå",
    "Country": "Sweden"
}]
```

Here is my AngularJS code :

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in stuff">
        <td>
            {{d.Name}}    
        </td>
        <td>
            {{d.Country}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{d.City}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above code works fine but the number of `td` has been hard coded. Is there any way to make it dynamic.

Comment: use angular template? `http://www.jptacek.com/2014/02/angularJS-templates/`  Not as elegant a solution as Simon has proposed, but would be a possibility for a variety of mixed data content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a second `ng-repeat` to your table:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in stuff">
        <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in d">
            {{value}}    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Its worth noting this will only be valid markup if all results in d are equal in length.

Comment: this is change the order of the column, because of angular will sort the object field according to key.

Comment: if you want a custom order you can use angulars orderBy in your ng-repeat... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: orderBy do not change the order of the columns instead it will order the table rows.

Comment: Use it in the second ng-repeat so the <td></td> is ordered.

Comment: using orderBy will re-order the data apear in the table it will not change the order of the columns

Comment: It will order the row if you use orderBy on the <tr>.... it will order the column if you use it on the <td></td> I don't understand why your saying it won't work?

Comment: `Orders a specified array by the expression predicate` from the doc

Comment: My bad forgot it was an object, in this care you can use a custom filter... http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/